# How to count values with a where condition where we can put a start date and end date based on other tables date

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

Order table - this table shows the orders completed in 5 delivery days (Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon). There are fixed 5 delivery Days. This table has order_id, cust_id, DeliveryDay, status (completed, processing, etc)

2nd tables - selection tables- It shows the number of products a subscriber selected to be delivered in that particular week. They can select from any of 20 products in that week. The number of products are the same but, products get changed every week. Now in this table, we do have a selection for all the people who might have selected 4-5 weeks before as well but now they might have canceled the subscription.

Selection table have - Cust_id, Product_id, ProductSlot, startDate(Thursday, as weeks, starts from Thursday).

So I am interested in knowing the actual number of selections for only those people who had actually got their order delivered (status in order table - Completed)in that particular week. How can I add a condition that if the order is completed within those 5 days(week in selection table) and then count the selections by product Id?

```
Select product_id, cust_id, startDate, Number 
from selections S
Group by product_id
join orders O on S.cust_id = O.cust_id
where orders.status in('completed', processing)
```

this query is giving the wrong result because it's not taking the delivery dates into consideration.

Selection table - [image: Selection table]

Order Table - [image: Order Table]

Output - [image: output]

only count the completed orders within delivered in those 5 days(Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon) and ignore any failed orders and its product selections. IN selection table a customer with cust_id 1239 has selected 2 products but his order has failed status in order table so don't count his products.

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL? Please do not add tags for databases not involved

Comment: What else have you tried so far? Are you searching for a solution in MySQL, or in PostgreSQL?

Comment: MYSQL. I tried to add - LEFT JOIN orders O on S.cust_id = O.cust_id AND S.startDate BETWEEN O.deliveydate AND O.deliverydate. Just trying to figure out.

Comment: Give us sample data and expected result pls!!